# Updating table with composite primary key using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table named `tblUserNetwork`. It contains `composite primary key` on `UserID` and `ConnectedToUserID`

When i update the table `networks.Update(networks)`, it gives error like this:

```
Table dbo.tblUserNetwork contains a composite primary key field
```

What is the problem in updating.

I am updating many other table they don't have composite primary key they are updating well and good. But this does't, I cant understand this problem.

Is there ant problem with `composite primary key`

Answer (score 2):

General help for [handle composite keys in linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399391.aspx).

Could you supply an example code for your problem?